# Why does python beat c++ in for loops?

Tags: python, c++

Here is my c++code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    clock_t end;
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cout << "Test" << endl;
    }
    end = clock() - start;
    double duration = end / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Duration: " << duration << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
} // This takes around ~ .9 secs on average
```

Here is my python code:

```
import time

def foo():
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1000):
        print('Test')
    print('Duration: {}'.format(time.time()-start))

# This takes around ~ .08 secs on average
```

why is PYTHON FASTER in this case? I'm not sure if it's because I wrote extra code or not, but it seems like a pretty basic for loop.

Comment: It's not the loops, it is the content in the loops.

Comment: Try again with `static const char text[] = "Test\n";`..., `cout.write(text, sizeof(text) - 1);`.

Comment: The biggest potential offenders are: compiling in debug mode without optimizations and std::cout. Use fputs and make sure you compile with -O2 and without -D_DEBUG.

Comment: I just executed your code (unmodified) on my machine and the timings I get are: `C++ with endl: 0.001654, C++ without endl: 0.001555, python3 without flush: 0.003866910934448242, python3 with flush: 0.005127906799316406`.

Comment: @LakshayGarg What compiler, stdlib, and optimization flags? I vaguely remember that either libc++ or libstdc++ has an optimization the other one doesn't, where it can detect flush requests that come at the end of a line on a line-buffered output file, which speeds up `endl` on `cout` to a tty, but… I can't remember any details, or find any info in a search.

Comment: @abarnert Compiler: Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2), flags: -O3. stdlib: libc++

Comment: Well I'm a noob, I was using visual studio local windows debugger, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not the `for` loop that's slow, but the C++ `iostreams`. And it's not even that `iostreams` is horribly slow,<sup>1</sup> but that you're doing an `endl` for every line.

C++ [`endl`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/) is not just a synonym for `'\n'`, it's an io manipulator object that, when inserted into a stream, inserts `'\n'` *and then asks for the stream to be flushed.* Flushing stdout can be very slow.

Python [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), on the other hand, doesn't flush unless you ask it to explicitly; otherwise, it just writes to `sys.stdout`, which is a `TextIOWrapper` that accumulates stuff in a buffer and flushes whenever it thinks is appropriate, which is pretty much the same thing C++ `iostreams` do.<sup>2</sup>

For a fair test, compare this:

```
    cout << "Test\n";

    print("Test")
```

… or this:

```
    cout << "Test" << endl;

    print("Test", flush=True)
```

---

<sub>1. With some platforms/compilers/optimization flags, it *is* pretty slow. And manipulators can be especially slow. So Python might *still* beat C++ after you fix this problem. But not by an 11:1 ratio.</sub>

<sub>2. Python also has to convert your string from Unicode to `sys.stdout.encoding`. But, if you're on 3.4 or later, a Unicode string that happens to be all ASCII like `'test'` is stored as the ASCII bytes, and encoding it is a no-op.</sub>

Comment: What exactly iostreams do is implementation-dependent. Microsoft's implementation of `std::cout` is not buffered. It would write characters one by one to the underlying file with `fputc`.

Comment: @AlexeyB: It is unbuffered to synchronize with `<stdio.h>`. Call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` and it should become buffered. While flushing every line is bad, the most likely cause of bad timing is actually not optimizing the code.